# Calculator keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, calculator

Keyboard calculator shortcut don't works with eOS 6 Odin.

I opened a issue on the app's Github but it doesn't depend on it.
Comments can help to find a solution : https://github.com/elementary/calculator/issues/200

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Custom*.
[image]
Then add a new custom shortcut with command:

```
flatpak run io.elementary.calculator
```

Finally, set the key to launch it as any key combination you like.

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not work, even after rebooting.

Only this hack works for the moment:
https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/pgkaah/fix_the_calculator_keyboard_shortcut/

According to the comments on Github, it's hardcoded into gnome-settings-daemon, so setting a custom shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: Adding a link to the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/elementary/calculator/issues/200).